# I am getting an errror while clicking the button of producing sound

Tags: javascript, html

Whenever I want to play the sound of the
word it doesn't play that sound and gives me an error of "The element has no supported sources".

Have a look into this please and let me know where I'm doing something wrong.

**Html**

```
<audio id="micCheck"></audio>
<div id="container">
  <div id="box-1">
    <input
      type="text"
      placeholder="Type your word here.."
      id="searchWord"
    />
    <button id="btn">Search</button>
  </div>
  <div class="output" id="output"></div>
</div>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

**Javascript**

```
const searchButton = document.getElementById("btn");
const searchField = document.getElementById("searchWord");
const volume = document.getElementById("micCheck");
const url = "https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/api/v2/entries/en/";

searchButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  let saveWord = searchField.value;
  fetch(`${url}${saveWord}`)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((values) => {
      console.log(values);
      output.innerHTML = `
      <div id="box-2">
      <h3>${values[0].word}</h3>
      <button onclick="playSound()">
        <i class="fas fa-volume-up">
        </i>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div id="box-3">
      <p>${values[0].meanings[0].partOfSpeech}</p>
      <p> ${values[0].phonetic} </p>
    </div>

    <div id="box-4">
      <p>
      ${values[0].meanings[0].definitions[0].definition}</br>
      </p>
      <p id="paragraph-2">
    ${values[0].meanings[0].definitions[0].example || ""}
      </p>`;
      volume.setAttribute("src", `https:${values[0].phonetics[0].audio}`);
    });
});

function playSound() {
  volume.play();
}
```

Comment: Are you meant to be using the [Web Speech API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Speech_API)?

Comment: The problem is with ``https:${values[0].phonetics[0].audio}`` - you are manually adding the `https` escheme to the url that already contains it, so change to `audio.setAttribute("src", values[0].phonetics[0].audio);`

Comment: This error typically occurs when the browser is unable to find a valid audio file to play. This could be because the src attribute of your audio element is empty, or because it's pointing to a URL that doesn't contain an audio file. try to use fix src value to start the debugging process

Comment: You also probably want to clear the cached result with each new search otherwise the same word will be read out if there is no match

Comment: I am using APIS to fetch the data. Everything was working fine but when i click on the button to get the sound of the searched word i got an error that "The element has no supported sources".

Comment: Thankyou guys, it's working fine now but for some of the words it doesn't give me the sound and showing me the same error what can be the reason for that ?

Comment: `"it doesn't give me the sound"` - that is down to the api and probably because they do not have whatever word recorded. You could use the  Web Speech API in such instances to play audio that is missing

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have no idea about Web Speech API as I consider myself a newbie, but I am going to look into this for sure.